# Change C++ Compiler in MonoDevelop

Tags: c++, macos, monodevelop

Is there a way to tell MonoDevelop to use a different C++ compiler? I want to use the latest g++ 4.7 that I installed via MacPorts, not the default 4.2 that comes with OS X.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your PATH environment variable to put the directory containing your g++ before the system one.